Start multiple program/command in the same windows but different tab
I am using Windows 11 and using a .bat script to start commands and scripts like this:
cd "path\to\something"
start "TITLE" cmd /k "a script or a command like npm/yarn"
[... repeat x times]

It works fine but I am looking for a way to:

Start every item in the same comand window but in distinct tab (it actually start X window with 1 tab each)
Every tab should have its specified title (I tried with the "title" command after the /k and &: "title something & command" without success)

Here is a picture to illustrate what I am looking for

Thanks for helping :)

Which program are you using as your "Comand window", which has a "tab" feature? Please update your question to make sure that any potential helpers can themselves reproduce your environment. If, for instance, you are talking about Windows Terminal, (which has extensive help on opening tabs), you should also use its tag, when you make that [Edit].
